# Two RewriteConds and One RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Following is my condition for Apache:

If help.shtml is present in the URL, then I would like to remove the parameter `sst=awesome` from the URL below

**Example:**

```
http://www.example.com/Example/res/help.shtml?trimQuery=Bla+Bla+Melt&op=search&Jtt=Bla+Bla+Melt&J=0&GlobalSearch=true&sst=awesome&cm_mmc=PPC
```

My output should be :

```
http://www.example.com/Example/res/help.shtml?trimQuery=Bla+Bla+Melt&op=search&Jtt=Bla+Bla+Melt&J=0&GlobalSearch=true&cm_mmc=PPC
```

I attempted to do this:

```
RewriteCond ^{/Example)?res/help.shtml.*$ <br/>
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)sst=awesome&?(.*)$
```

I dont know what the RewriteRule should be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)sst=awesome(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(Example)?res/help\.shtml$ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: Thanks! I have two conditions though 1) If help.shtml is in the URL 2) and if sst=awesome is present in the URL.   If above two conditions satisfy, then I need to remove sst=awesome from the query string

Comment: If you closely look at my code I have both conditions included. URI is matched in `RewriteRule` itself.

Comment: Thank you - I see it now.   Do you know of any RewriteRules testers?  I used this http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/ and does not identify a match for the URL.   I do not have access to the apache yet and hence looking for a tester.

Comment: Online testers don't work well. Better to test it on your localhost.

Comment: Will test when I have access to apache and will be sure to mark it as accepted, Thanks.  One question -In the RewriteRule, you have help\.shtml, should it be help.shtml?

Comment: No dot should be escaped in regex otherwise it matches any character.

Comment: What does %1%2 mean in my current example?  There is no documentation about this and hence.

Comment: `%1 and %2` are back references to text captured in `RewriteCond`

Comment: We have the following three lines.   We would like for the param sst=subset to be dropped and fed to the next RewriteRule that would make it /search with all other parameters intact (except sst=subste)...not sure, why it is not working:      <br/>RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)sst=subset(.*)$  <br />

RewriteRule ^(Example)?wwg/search\.shtml$ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [NC,R]
<br />
RewriteRule ^(/Example)?/wwg/search.shtml.*$ /search [R=301,L]

Comment: when i attempt to go here: http://hostname/Example/wwg/search.shtml?searchQuery=Blue+Ice+Melt&op=search&Ntt=Blue+Ice+Melt&N=0&GlobalSearch=true&sst=subset&cm_mmc=PPC   I should be redirect here
http://hostname/search?searchQuery=Blue+Ice+Melt&op=search&Ntt=Blue+Ice+Melt&N=0&GlobalSearch=true&sst=subset&cm_mmc=PPC

Comment: sorry, wrong scenario - when I attempt to go here http://hostname/Example/wwg/search.shtml?searchQuery=Blue+Ice+Melt&op=search&Ntt=Blue+Ice+Melt&N=0&GlobalSearch=true&sst=subset&cm_mmc=PPC     I should go here:
http://hostname/search?searchQuery=Blue+Ice+Melt&op=search&Ntt=Blue+Ice+Melt&N=0&GlobalSearch=true&cm_mmc=PPC

Comment: What is location of your .htaccess? Is it in `Example/` folder?

Comment: I do not know where it is located as I do not have access, will send info as soon as I have access.     I made a few more changes as I noticed that in the first RewriteRule it was ^(Example), I think it should be ^(/Example)..  Also, .*$ was missing in the first RewriteRule after search\.shtml so I added them.  Still no luck yet.  It says "Bad request"

Comment: No it should start without leading `/` and this answer will vary based on the location of the .htaccess. Once you find out that just leave a comment here.

Comment: OK, will do.  Considering how the existing Rewrite URL(see below) looks like this  - I am guessing that the new RewriteRule also should have ^(/Example)  This is the existing RewriteRule   RewriteRule ^(/Example)?/wwg/search.shtml.*$ /search [R=301,L]

Comment: If you have `RewriteRule ^(/Example)?...` in your .htaccess then **it is not working**

Comment: So, the steps are 1) Remove sst=subset from the URL parameter ONLY if the request is for search.shtml.  After removal, all of the URL will remain intact except losing sst=subset  2) Thereafter, the existing Rewrite Rule that I posted above Rewrites the URL to go to /search instead of /Exampe/wwg/search.shtml and keeps all other URL params intact.  Just wanted to ensure I explained the situation correctly.  Thank you much for your help.

Comment: Just to be clear, the existing Rewrite Rule which is RewriteRule ^(/Example)?/wwg/search.shtml.*$ /search [R=301,L] works fine.  Hence, I am wondering if the new RewriteRule for step 1) above should also have ^(/Example)

Comment: If you seem to have figured out everything then why did you even ask a question here? You don't even know the location of your .htaccess and running with all the theories here. Sorry this is pure a Q&A site wher e you ask a question and get an answer.

Comment: No I have not figured out anything Sir.  I am still seeking your help, I just wanted to ensure that I have stated the scenario correctly, thats all.

Comment: Will stop theorizing and will let you know where the htaccess file is located when I find out.  Sorry do not have access to the box hence shooting in the dark here.  thanks again for your patience and help.

Comment: Update:  Still do not have access to server and no one can tell me where htaccess file is located.  Will send an update as soon as I know.  Thanks.

Comment: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)sst=subset&?(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)search.shtml(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1?%1%2 [NC,R]
I tried above but causes a bad request 400 error

Comment: I have basically no clue about local setup and why you have zero byte file. I cannot provide continuous long term support to one specific problem. Test it on your localhost by setting up env.